# Beginner Scheme: Procedures that return themselves

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, tail-recursion

This is an example from the book I am reading:

```
1    (define (length items)
2     (define (length-iter a count)
3       (if (null? a)
4           count
5           (length-iter (cdr a)(+ 1 count))))
6      (length-iter items 0))
```

What I am not understanding is how can `length-iter` know about count? The first time this
procedure is called with a `list`, it will in turn define another procedure with two argumenets, I get that much. But how does it know that `a` is the `list items`? It hasnt reached line 6 yet, where `items` is passed to `length-iter` as the argument `a`. Somehow though it already knows this and is able to make the computation. Any help in clarifying this a bit is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts in the `length` function:

1. *Definition* of the inner function `length-iter`;
2. *Invocation* of the inner function `length-iter`.

In the invocation, i.e., line 6, you *pass* the original `items` list to the inner function as an **argument**. This is where the inner function gets called. Previously, you are just *defining* the function, not *calling* it:

```
(length-iter items 0)
```

Thus, `items` will be bound to `a`, and  `0` to `count`. You can think of the inner function as a separate function:

```
(define (length-iter a count)
  (if (null? a)
      count
      (length-iter (cdr a)(+ 1 count))))
```

And then, think of your `length` function as if it just delegated all the work to the `length-iter` function:

```
(define (length items)
  (length-iter items 0))
```

That's what's being done in your function. The difference, is that the `length-iter` function is only known to `length`.

Comment: Oh ok that really helped to think of them as two separate procedures. I was thinking it rolled right into `length-iter` before it was called with the arguments. Thanks!